# Using Dropbox Generated Access Token with DropNetRT

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I'm using the DropNetRT library and I can't find a way to create a working DropNetClient using just the Generated Access Token from my app page in my Dropbox account.

If I use my User Secret and User Token it works:

```
public static async Task UploadStuff()
{
    DropNetClient client = new DropNetClient("APIKey", "AppSecret");
    client.SetUserToken(new UserLogin() { Secret = "mySecret", Token = "myToken" });
    // Then upload the data with the client
}
```

But, instead of my UserToken and UserSecret, I just want to use my Generated Access Token.

It looks something like this, just to be sure:

> jfjfDkFkdfikAAAAAAAAAADkfkDJSJFJISjofdjFjjfoJOIDJSOjsFKPFKPEJKfjiksfd3_thD

Now, I tried using a UserLogin with just my Access Token as the Token and without a UserSecret, but the client threw an exception, so I guess that's not the right way to do that.

How can I do that? Is there a way to create a client with the access token with this library, or do I have to upload the file manually using an HttpClient? If so, I really have no idea on how to do that.

Thanks!

Sergio

**Edit:** this is what I tried (it's not working):

```
public static async Task TestUploadGeneratedToken()
{
    // Create the client
    DropNetClient client = new DropNetClient("APIKey", "AppSecret");
    client.SetUserToken("MyGeneratedAccessToken", String.Empty);

    // Get a test file
    StorageFile tempFile = await ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.CreateFileAsync("test.txt", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
    await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(tempFile, "This is a simple test file");

    // Convert the file to a byte array
    IRandomAccessStream stream = await tempFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
    stream.Seek(0);
    byte[] bytes = new byte[stream.Size];
    await stream.ReadAsync(bytes.AsBuffer(), (uint)stream.Size, InputStreamOptions.None);

    // Upload the file
    await client.Upload(CrashReportPath, "tokenTest.txt", bytes);
}
```

the Upload method throws a DropboxException.

Answer (score 0):

That looks right. Try setting the secret to string.empty instead of null?

I'm not sure if I have used a generated token before but can't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Hey man, thanks for your answer. I tried but I still get an exception when I upload the file, I updated my question with a code example. I hope that can help :) If I call the SetUserToken with a UserLogin instance with my UserToken and UserLogin (the ones I get from the standard login procedure) it works fine. It just won't work with the GeneratedAccessToken only. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Looks like the problem is the token is oauth2 but DropNetRT only does Oauth1 at the moment. Sorry, will need to update the library for Oauth2 but the older DropNet works with Oauth2 tokens.

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking forward to trying the new update for DropNetRT then :) In the meantime I'll keep using the login with my UserToken and UserSecret, I just don't know how long they will last, or if there's a limit for the number of API calls I can do using these credentials.